# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load libnative_activity: findLibrary returned null

Tags: android, opencv

I try to run the opencv4android native sample

My device is ZTE Blade android 2.3.7 and the version of opencv manager is 2.4.9

I got the following

```
error = java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load native_activity: findLibrary returned null
```

I changed the `System.loadLibrary("native_activity");` to `System.loadLibrary("libnative_activity");` but always the same error

```
AndroidRuntime(1696): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load libnative_activity: findLibrary returned null
```